# Nested quotes in bash -- passing single argument containing spaces

Tags: bash, shell, nested, quotes

script.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "First argument: $1"
```

wrapper.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
CALLER='./script.sh "this should be one argument"'
$CALLER
```

what happens:

```
$ ./wrapper.sh 
First argument: "this
```

what I was expecting:

```
$ ./wrapper.sh 
First argument: this should be one argument
```

I tried different exercises to make it work the way I want it, but I can't find the way to invoke script.sh with single argument containing spaces from within wrapper.sh.
I would also like to understand the way nested quotes are interpreted.

Comment: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050

Answer (score 1):

This works instead (only last line changed):

```
#!/bin/bash
CALLER='./script.sh "this should be one argument"'
eval "$CALLER"
```

The reason for this is that quoting is applied at a different place in the parsing process than variable substitution, so you need to re-run the result of the substitution (`$CALLER`) through the parsing process (using `eval`), but quoted (the `"…"` around `$CALLER`) to avoid the field splitting that comes with the substitution already.

Further reading: [the POSIX documentation on this](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06), and the links already given in comments.